# Justfy rewrite of odds equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

By what algebraic rules can we rewrite $\frac{p}{1-p} = a$  to  $p = \frac{a}{a+1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$\frac{p}{1-p} = a$

$p = a(1-p)$

$p = a - ap$

$(a + 1)p = a$

$\boxed{p = \frac{a}{a + 1}}$